# change attribute value in xml in Objective C using GDataXML

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xml-parsing, gdataxml

I want to change attribute value of this XML

```
<btn1 btnID="1">
   <ch1 state="1" value="250" dimspeed="8" />
</btn1>
```

I want to change state value from 0 to 1 and vice versa dynamically. Also I want to change "value" and "dimspeed" dynamically.

But I could not get any option to do this.

I know it's possible in many other programming language like PHP, android, C# but I could not find any option in objective c. I have gone through 2-3 xml parser and right now I am using GDataXMLParser. Can anybody please help me?

Here is complete XML File

```
<units>
<unit mac="A0.36.119.80.203.67" ip="192.168.2.118" port="000001001" type="abc" name="cda">
<ch1 state="1" value="50" dimspeed="8" color="w">Channel 1</ch1>
<ch2 state="1" value="50" dimspeed="8" color="w">Channel 2</ch2>
<ch3 state="1" value="50" dimspeed="8" color="w">Channel 3</ch3>
<ch4 state="1" value="50" dimspeed="8" color="w">Channel 4</ch4>
<ch5 state="1" value="50" dimspeed="8" color="w">Channel 5</ch5>
<ch6 state="1" value="50" dimspeed="8" color="w">Channel 6</ch6>
<ch7 state="1" value="50" dimspeed="8" color="w">Channel 7</ch7>
<ch8 state="1" value="50" dimspeed="8" color="w">Channel 8</ch8>
<ch9 state="1" value="50" dimspeed="8" color="w">Channel 9</ch9>
<ch10 state="1" value="50" dimspeed="8" color="w">Channel 10</ch10>
<ch11 state="1" value="50" dimspeed="8" color="w">Channel 11</ch11>
<ch12 state="1" value="50" dimspeed="8" color="w">Channel 12</ch12>
<btn1 btnID="1">
   <ch1 state="1" value="250" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch2 state="1" value="250" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch3 state="1" value="250" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch4 state="1" value="250" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch5 state="1" value="250" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch6 state="1" value="250" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch7 state="1" value="250" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch8 state="1" value="250" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch9 state="1" value="250" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch10 state="1" value="250" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch11 state="1" value="250" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch12 state="1" value="250" dimspeed="8" />
</btn1>
<btn2 btnID="2">
   <ch1 state="1" value="187" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch2 state="1" value="187" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch3 state="1" value="187" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch4 state="1" value="187" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch5 state="1" value="187" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch6 state="1" value="187" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch7 state="1" value="187" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch8 state="1" value="187" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch9 state="1" value="187" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch10 state="1" value="187" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch11 state="1" value="187" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch12 state="1" value="187" dimspeed="8" />
</btn2>
<btn3 btnID="3">
   <ch1 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch2 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch3 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch4 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch5 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch6 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch7 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch8 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch9 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch10 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch11 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch12 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
</btn3>
<btn4 btnID="4">
   <ch1 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch2 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch3 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch4 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch5 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch6 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch7 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch8 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch9 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch10 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch11 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch12 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
</btn4>
<btn5 btnID="5">
   <ch1 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch2 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch3 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch4 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch5 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch6 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch7 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch8 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch9 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch10 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch11 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch12 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
</btn5>
<btn6 btnID="6">
   <ch1 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch2 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch3 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch4 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch5 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch6 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch7 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch8 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch9 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch10 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch11 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
   <ch12 state="1" value="125" dimspeed="8" />
</btn6>
</unit>
```

Comment: String replacement would not be useful?

Comment: How are you planning to find out the element to be edited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify a GDataXMLElement constructed using that XML by doing the following:

```
NSString *XMLString = @"<btn1 btnID=\"1\">\
<ch1 state=\"1\" value=\"250\" dimspeed=\"8\" />\
</btn1>";
NSError *error = nil;
GDataXMLElement *newElement = [[GDataXMLElement alloc] initWithXMLString: XMLString error: &error];
NSLog(@"New element: %@ error: %@", newElement, error);
if(nil == error)
{
  GDataXMLElement *childElement = [[newElement elementsForName: @"ch1"] objectAtIndex: 0];;
  [[childElement attributeForName: @"value"] setStringValue: @"500"];
}
NSLog(@"New element now: %@", newElement);
```

This changes the value of the attribute named "value" from 250 to 500, as the output shows:

```
2013-06-14 12:51:12.406 TestApp[532:907] New element: GDataXMLElement 0x1f814790: {type:1 name:btn1 xml:"<btn1 btnID="1"><ch1 state="1" value="250" dimspeed="8"/></btn1>"} error: (null)
2013-06-14 12:51:16.223 TestApp[532:907] New element now: GDataXMLElement 0x1f814790: {type:1 name:btn1 xml:"<btn1 btnID="1"><ch1 state="1" value="500" dimspeed="8"/></btn1>"}
```